# spring - using google guava cache

Tags: java, spring, caching, google-guava-cache

I'm trying to use google guava cache in my spring app, but result is never caching.

This are my steps:

in conf file:

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class myConfiguration {
        @Bean(name = "CacheManager")
        public CacheManager cacheManager() {
            return new GuavaCacheManager("MyCache");
        }
}
```

In class I want to use caching:

```
public class MyClass extends MyBaseClass {
    @Cacheable(value = "MyCache")
    public Integer get(String key) {
        System.out.println("cache not working");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Then when I'm calling:

```
MyClass m = new MyClass();
m.get("testKey");
m.get("testKey");
m.get("testKey");
```

It's entering function each time and not using cache:
console:

```
 cache not working
 cache not working 
 cache not working
```

Does someone have an idea what am I missing or how can I debug that?

Comment: Have you added a CacheBuilder into your spring config?

Comment: And why should it work? You are creating a new instance of the class yourself, whereas you should a spring configured (and thus proxied) instance for caching to work.

Comment: @m. Deinum Can you explain? what do you mean spring configured instance?

Comment: Spring uses AOP to apply caching, however you are using your own instance of `MyClass` which isn't being proxied by spring. Regardless how much configuration you are going to throw at it, it will not work. Configure the `MyClass` as a spring bean, get an/the instance from the context and use that instead of your own instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not manage a spring bean by yourself. Let spring to manage it.

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class myConfiguration {
        @Bean(name = "CacheManager")
        public CacheManager cacheManager() {
            return new GuavaCacheManager("MyCache");
        }

        @Bean
        public MyClass myClass(){
            return new MyClass();
        }
}
```

After that you should use MyClass in a managed manner.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(myConfiguration.class);
    final MyClass myclass = applicationContext.getBean("myClass");
    myclass.get("testKey");
    myclass.get("testKey");
    myclass.get("testKey");
}
```